# standard latex font in lyx

Tags: fonts, lyx

By default, LyX sets font to be Times New Roman in the article class. When I print my document it looks different than most other latex documents which seem to be using a different font. What font/size is the standard for latex documents?

The following packages in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=20pt}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\setcitestyle{round}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\let\footnoterule\relax}{}{}{}
```

Comment: I would think you've changed some setting, as LyX does not set normally have Times as the default font. Which roman font is selected in Document --> Settings --> Fonts?

Comment: Default is selected.  However, this is clearly not the Latex font.

Comment: Default should make Computer Modern (or Latin Modern) the document font. Any packages in the preamble?

Comment: just added to the question with the packages

Comment: Have you clicked "save as default" before? That might have changed the default font settings. In any case, you can always select `lmodern` in the font setting. That should give you the default font seen in usual LaTeX documents.

Comment: No font packages there, so Kevin could be right, that you've changed the default settings.

Comment: thanks guys, gave this a shot. maybe it's the size and not the font. this is pretty trivial. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard font used by TeX is called Computer Modern, but some document classes may use a different font. The default size also depends on document class, but for the standard classes (`book`, `article`, `report`) at least it is 10pt.

LyX does not change this, so Computer Modern is the default here as well. If they are not used, either you're using a document class that specifies a different font, or you've added a font package to the preamble, or you've at some point changed the LyX default settings.

To make Computer Modern (or the new derivative, Latin Modern, which looks similar) the default, go to Document --> Settings --> Fonts, select one of these for the Roman font (and possibly for Sans Serif and Typewriter as well), and click the button labeled *Save as document defaults*.